# AngularJS component attributes not recognised in WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, angularjs-components

WebStorm 2016.2.3 does not seem to recognise AngularJS component attributes in the way that it does with directive attributes:

[image]

Is there a way to set up WebStorm to recognise component attributes?